# inside one level deeep of for loop we cant access index

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
function lonelyinteger(a) {
    // Write your code here
    var temp = a;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        const index = temp.indexOf(a[i]);
        temp.splice(index,1);
        console.log(`The new array ${temp}`);
        console.log(`Searching for the newest value ${a[i]}`);
        const isExist = temp.indexOf(a[i]);
        console.log(`Checking weather the value exist or not ${isExist}`)
        console.log(`the value of index is ${i}`)
        if(isExist=== -1){
            console.log(`The value i have finded who is lonely is ${a[i]}`);
            // return a[i];
        }
    }
    }
    
    array = [1,1,2]
    
    lonelyinteger(array)
```

What i am doing is looping the array i want to find the number which is single there is one integer in my test who is like that he have no buddy so i write the program but inside the for loop at If exist i am getting undefined why is that i am not able the finded value

Comment: Can you please split your single phrase into multiple phrases, using punctuation, so it becomes more understandable?

Comment: `temp.splice(index,1);` splices also `a`, `var temp = a;` doesn't make a copy of the array, it just copies a reference to the same array.